# How can I restore the look of the original icons to my Windows 7 Desktop?

Tags: icons

I'm not sure what caused this, but in the last several days all but five of my many Desktop icons (O/S is Windows 7) have changed as follows: added onto the original icon design is a smaller-sized vertical rectangle with a turned-down edge on the upper-right.   How can I get rid of this addition to show the original icon?  Clicking on the icons boots up whatever program the icon is for -- there is no problem there; it's just that I prefer the look of the originals.

[image: altered icon v.2 for Word.jpg]

Comment: Maybe a screenshot of the changed icons would help someone recognize the culprit.

Comment: I created a screenshot of one of the altered icons -- how do I paste it to this posting in the forum?

Comment: Edit your original question with the "edit" button under your tags, and press ctrl+g in the editor. [This](https://superuser.com/editing-help) may be a helpful read. Perhaps add a couple more tags while you're at it, like "windows-7"

Comment: Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: Dial: See if I followed your instructions correctly to upload an image of one of my altered icons -- for Word for Windows .

Comment: I believe there was a very similar question asked not too long ago. This isn't the icon itself, but an application putting an overlay over the icon, that is failing.

Comment: Just now checked my Desktop and the overlays have gone...as they did yesterday, when they began appearing...later in the day they were gone.  I'll keep checking SuperUser to see if anyone knows what application on my Windows 7-based laptop might be causing the overlay to appear on the icons.  Once again, this does not seem to be adversely affecting my ability to boot up any program or app, it's just that I prefer the original icon design rather than have the overlap clutter up the icon.  Thanks to all for your suggestions and help.  Adman

Comment: No, my mistake --the overlays on my icons aren't gone after all -- they've been replaced with another design...instead of the small rectangle designed placed over the icon, I now have a gold star overlaid on each.  I think the suggestion that some application residing on my laptop is causing this.  Adman

Comment: Maybe this can be fixed in different modes. It seems it is because the Icon cache can't be updated well.

Comment: I am completely puzzled by this -- the first overlay was the vertical rectangle with a turned-down upper -right corner, then all the icons that had that on them now featured a gold star, which in turn was replaced by a small arrow at the lower-left -- which is a fairly common overlay, and now -- no overlays at all.  Since none of these seem to affect my being able to boot up a program or app, I'm going to file this away as "not worth getting upset about."